# Why my async task is too slow when it uses in pager adapter

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-pageradapter

I am using the following code

```
ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter= new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

My SectionsPagerAdapter  class is 

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
            Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            int numpages = 0;

            numpages=5;

            return numpages;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            // Locale l = Locale.getDefault();

            String chnl_name = "";
            switch (language) {
            case 1:
                chnl_name = Constants.telugu_channels[position];
                break;
            case 2:
                chnl_name = Constants.tamil_channels[position];
                break;
            case 3:
                chnl_name = Constants.english_channels[position];
                break;
            case 4:
                chnl_name = Constants.hindi_channels[position];
                break;
            }

            return chnl_name;
        }
    }
```

and fragment class is

```
// enter code here

public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {

        GridView gridplaylst;
        ProgressBar progress;

        Play_list playlist;
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_grid, container,
                    false);

            // dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
            // ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));

            gridplaylst = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridplaylst);
            progress = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progress);

            if (playlist != null)
                playlist.cancel(true);
            if (language != 0) {
                int a = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);

                switch (language) {

                case 1:

                    playlist = new Play_list(
                            Constants.telugu_playlists[getArguments().getInt(
                                    ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) - 1]);
                    playlist.execute();
                    break;
                case 2:

                    new Play_list(Constants.tamil_playlists[getArguments()
                            .getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) - 1]).execute();

                    break;
                case 3:

                    new Play_list(Constants.english_playlists[getArguments()
                            .getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) - 1]).execute();

                    break;
                case 4:
                    new Play_list(Constants.hindi_playlists[getArguments()
                            .getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) - 1]).execute();

                    break;
                }

            }
}
```

and playlist is a async task like

```
public class Play_list extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {
protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {

}
}
```

Here all the functionality is working fine, but my problem is the data downloading by the async tasks is too slow.

I think the problem is creating a new task every time.

Please suggest me how can i overcome this problem.

Comment: I think that we must find where the time is used to do something. try adding log when Async Task start, stop, and before/after the task creation. Then you can understand if the problem is the creation, or the execution of the background task...

Answer (score 0):

@Prakash : There is a catch while you use ViewPager. [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) will start preparing view for next 2 fragments and as when your activity with ViewPager is called by System , ViewPager will creating next 2 views that you have defined in FragmentPagerAdapter.

You can use setOffscreenPageLimit(pagestoCache) to minimize this functionality.

Prakash , now you have to call asyn task only when fragment is visible to user and cancel if user moves out of current fragment. Why i am asking because if you are not cancelling the Aync task there will be many thread will be running in application space. You can also chaeck if you can use ThreadPoolExecutor in your code.

Comment: Here the Problem is the adapter is loading better for first time but if you swipe two three times continuously the downloading task become too worst.

Comment: @PrakashVitala you're encountering memory fragmentation - everytime you swipe your ViewPager, one fragment is destroyed and another one is recreated the way Roll No1 explained.

AFAIK - you can use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to avoid recreating this fragments on scrolling.

Comment: Hi Roll,  Can please suggest me how can i cancel a async task. Please suggest me a example.

Comment: @PrakashVitala : You have to call AyncTask method cancel(true) to cancel the task.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the fact, that Android does not run AsyncTasks in parallel? If you start many AsyncTasks in a row, they are queued and executed one after the other?

You can overcome this, by starting them with `executeOnExecutor(...)` instead of regular `execute()`.